# Typescript declaration merging to expand or override module type or interface property

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router

I'm using the types from `@types/react-router-dom` version `4.3.1` which imports types from `@types/react-router` and `@types/history`.

In my application I always have two properties in the location state and I want them to automatically be pulled from the `RouteComponentProps` interface, without having to pass a custom `LocationState` type variable to the interface every time.

The definition of the `RouteComponentProps` interface is in `react-router` and it goes as follows:

```
import * as H from 'history';

export interface RouteComponentProps<Params extends { [K in keyof Params]?: string } = {}, C extends StaticContext = StaticContext, S = H.LocationState> {
  history: H.History;
  location: H.Location<S>;
  match: match<Params>;
  staticContext?: C;
}
```

The definitions of the referenced interfaces/types from `history` are:

```
export interface Location<S = LocationState> {
    pathname: Pathname;
    search: Search;
    state: S;
    hash: Hash;
    key?: LocationKey;
}

export type LocationState = History.LocationState;

export namespace History {
    export type LocationState = any;
}
```

What I want is to expand the Location interface's state property type definition to include a custom interface (i.e. include the properties that are always available). So something like `state: S & { A: string; B: string; }`.

I have tried redeclaring the `RouteComponentProps` interface inside a module declaration for `react-router` but everything I try results in `All declarations of 'RouteComponentProps' must have identical type parameters.ts(2428)` or `Subsequent property declarations must have the same type.  Property 'location' must be of type 'Location<S>', but here has type 'any'.ts(2717)`.

I have also tried redeclaring the `Location` interface inside the history module declaration with the same result. After which I've tried redeclaring the `LocationState` type both inside and outside the `History`namespace but that always results in `Duplicate identifier 'LocationState'.ts(2300)`.

Is there anything I can do to get the desired behaviour **other than writing a custom interface for `RouteComponentProps` with a different name**? I want to be able to import that interface in the project, extend a component's props with it and have properties' `A` and `B` types accessible from `props.location.state` but also to be able to treat any other properties as `any`, **without passing a type variable definition every time**.

Comment: Noticed this question getting some traction, so just to comment that I didn't find a way to do this with the same name. I made a type `CustomRouteComponentProps<P, C, S extends { A: string; B: string; }> = RouteComponentProps<Params, C, S>` and did _find and replace_ on all files that used the type

Comment: It is not answering the question, but I'd suggest to migrate to v5 which comes with built in types and may possibly solve these issues

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So basically, what you are trying to achieve is called `module augmentation`.
Since it is **not possible to change the type of an existing property** (for obvious reason, it would break everything that already depends on that), the only way is to augment the Location with a new property that would **hold your
custom properties**.

```
// global.d.ts

import { State, Key, Path } from "history"

declare module 'history' {
  export interface Location<S extends State = State> extends Path {
    state: S;
    customState: { A: string; B: string; }
    key: Key;
  }
}
```

So, where you are adding those properties, if you want the `Location` to be
properly typed, you have no choice than using a custom property.

The other solution you know it, it is to create a new interface that you will use everywhere.

With the module augmentation at least, even if you need a new property, you do not have to re-type everything everywhere.

Hope that this little explanation will help you out.

Cheers,

Comment: I opted to just create a new interface to the module and do find & replace on the repo because I was typing existing functionality. If I ever encounter a similar issue while working on "fresh" code, I'd probably use the extra property approach you've described.

Answer (score 0):

This might not be the solution you're looking for but I usually have a custom interface for location (maybe export it from a shared `.ts` file on your app), then use `useLocation` hook with that interface.

```
import React, { ReactElement } from "react";
import { useLocation } from "react-router-dom";

interface CustomLocationState {
    A: string;
    B: string;
}

export default ():ReactElement => {
    const { state: {A, B} } = useLocation<CustomLocationState>();

    return <div>{A} - {B}</div>
}
```

Comment: As mentioned in the comments, the custom interface option is something I ended up doing, where I added that custom interface to the `react-router-dom` module. Also, this is a pre-hook question so this solution does not match the versions, but the use of the location is irrelevant - I just wanted to know if there was a way to override the existing interface. Either way, thanks for taking the time to answer such an old question :)

Comment: Sorry about that. Just realized it was an old question.